# How can I add a new preference to my eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, customization, preferences

I have an eclipse plugin. I want to add a new preference to this particular plugin. The type of preference is just a true/false kind of behavior which can be achieved with just a checkbox.

I have created this class

``

```
import org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditorPreferencePage;
import org.eclipse.jface.preference.BooleanFieldEditor;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPreferencePage;

import XXXXXXXXXX.MyPlugin;

/**
 * Preference page
 */
public class MyPreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

    public MyPreferencePage() {
        super(GRID);
        setPreferenceStore(MyPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
        setDescription(Messages.MyPreferencePage_PREFERENCES_DESCRIPTION);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the field editors. Field editors are abstractions of the common GUI blocks needed to
     * manipulate various types of preferences. Each field editor knows how to save and restore
     * itself.
     */
    @Override
    public void createFieldEditors() {
        addField(new BooleanFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.SHOW_REPORT,
                Messages.MyPreferencePage_SHOW_REPORT, getFieldEditorParent()));
    }

    @Override
    public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
    }
}
```

``

I have updated the extensions tab of plugin.xml accordingly.

Build is successful and I can see my newly created preference under windows -> preference. But when I click it, I can only see the description of the plugin. The boolean field which I have added is missing on the preference page.

Please help me in understanding what went wrong.

Comment: See https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html

Comment: Look at the `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages` extension point

Comment: @howlger and greg-449 Thanks for your help. I am getting an exception while clicking on the preference title. Please help.

Comment: Please show your code and tell the Java and Eclipse version that you use.

Comment: @howlger Eclipse version 4.11 java version 9.0.4

Comment: @howlger I have updated the code.